# Integral of log with an exponential inside. ln(x^13)

Tags: integration

I was wondering as to how to integrate logs with exponentials inside of them. Could you help me understand how this can be solved? I know the best way is to do it by parts, but I am not sure which variable to substitute.
$$\int_3^4 ln(x^{13}) dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\ln(x^{13})=13\ln(x)$$

if $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple property of $\ln$ that if you have $\ln(a^x)$, where $x>0$ (which it is in this case), then that is the same as $x \ln(a)$. So you can rewrite your integral as:

$$\int^{4}_{3}(13\ln(x))dx$$
$$13\int^{4}_{3}\ln(x)dx$$

Then just find the indefinite integral of $\ln(x)$ which is $x\ln \left(x\right)-x$.

Evaluate at boundaries.

$$[4\ln(4)-4]-[3\ln(3)-3] = 4\ln(4)-4-3\ln(3)+3=4\ln(4)-3\ln(3)-1$$

But remember we gotta multiply our answer by $13$.

So, we get:

$$52\ln(4) - 39\ln(3) - 13$$

Comment: Thanks, but I think it looks better if you factorise at the end.

Comment: Just my opinion, but $\ln4=2\ln2$.  :D

Comment: hmm I wonder who gave me the downvote and then the upvote haha

Comment: Lol, I only give upvotes to these good answers

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Rewrite the integral as
\begin{align}
13\int^4_3\ln x\ dx 
\end{align}
then use integration by parts where $u = \ln x$.

Comment: Thank you, that completely went out of my head.

Comment: @AlexFeklisov You may have forgotten, but you can upvote an answer by clicking the arrows on the left and you can mark answers that you feel best answer your question by clicking the checkmark below them.  :-)